# Connection refused when trying to connect to orderer service in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to deploy the automated hyperledger fabric using Kafka brokers environment from the github page https://github.com/xmhubj/fabric-kafka on minikube. When executing the create channel job, I get following error message:

```
UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 004 grpc: addrConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 10.106.33.24:7050: getsockopt: connection refused"; Reconnecting to {orderer0.ordererorg1:7050 <nil>}
Error: failed to create deliver client: orderer client failed to connect to orderer0.ordererorg1:7050: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded
```

The orderer is running as a service

```
ordererorg1   orderer0               NodePort    10.106.33.24     <none>        7050:32000/TCP.
```

If I do:

```
curl 10.106.33.24:7050
```

From within the cluster, I get:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.106.33.24 port 7050: Connection refused
```

Although it is a NodePort connection. Does anybody understand the problem and know how to fix it?

Edit:

```
$ kubectl get pods

org1          peer0-org1-575c96bc66-mdlb4                 1/1     Running     0          16h
org1          peer1-org1-5cfb47f59-d6prc                  1/1     Running     0          16h
```

Comment: What do your pods look like?  `kubectl get pods`?

Comment: I don't know why, but there are no pods associated to the orderer. However, this cannot be the reason since the peers, which do have pods running, are not reachable either.

Comment: please provide more details:
`kubectl get pods,svc,ep -o wide`
Did you try `curl <nodeport_ip>:32000` ?

Comment: could you please provide the output for `./setupNetwork.sh` ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the commentator who posted it deleted his comment, but yes, I did try <nodeport_ip>:32000. However, as I understand them, NodePorts make a service reachable from the outside through the port you indicated, but they do not hinder any incoming traffic from within the cluster on the primary port.

Comment: What do you mean by "output"? The content?

Comment: There is a lot of requirements inside the script - at the end:
`Please check the output of the above script, make sure no errors observed.`

Comment: There are no errors. Output: createchannel   0/1           17h        17h

Comment: As you can see, it has been in that loop for 16h.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196263/discussion-between-paul-rousseau-and-hanx).